# sample using spring security + openid for google apps hosted domains

Tags: spring-security, openid

Can any one help me to find the sample using spring security + openid for google apps hosted domains 
(for specific domain ie for services provided by google for organisation).

I found many samples related to openid and worked on those but i want specific for 
a domain  to develop a application.